# What exactly were the Prophets?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

So, within the DS9 universe, there were the Prophets that lived within the wormhole.

What sort of beings were they?  What were their powers?

Comment: Voted to close because this is *so easily* found on Wikipedia it should not be added here.

Comment: Being easy to find elsewhere is hardly a reason to close. There is no point in making it harder to find than necessary by artificially excluding it from this site, where it is certainly on-topic.

Comment: @Timwi: Stack Exchange does not aim at duplicating Wikipedia, there's [more to it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/about). We do not try to collect [facts easily found on a reference site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq). See [this thread on the Meta site](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197/should-trivially-easy-to-find-be-a-benchmark-for-moderating-the-site). In this case, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophet_%28Star_Trek%29) has low-quality banners, which makes me lean towards keeping the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The Prophets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole_Aliens) are a classic near god level race in the Star Trek universe, like the [Q](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28Star_Trek%29).

The wormhole aliens basically had unlimited power inside the [wormhole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole), existed mostly outside of time, and could spawn avatars.

The aliens appeared to have a vaguely defined amount of power outside the wormhole.
The wormhole aliens could engage in [Akira](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_%28film%29)-style [battles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reckoning_%28Star_Trek%3a_Deep_Space_Nine%29) with their nemesis the [Pah-wraiths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pah-wraith).  Who were of slightly less power, due to being kicked out of the wormhole.

The [Deep Space Nine series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_Deep_Space_Nine) does not go much further into their actual origins, but I know they are featured in the novels, of which I have read none.

Comment: I don't think they so much have control over time, as they lived outside of it, 'time' to them was a fixed point, and they didn't exist at any particular spot on it.  Their experience with time was similar to Dr. Manhattan's from Watchmen, only without the limitation of living within the timestream (and thus having your actions pre-determined).  It's implied that Sisko was pulled into this 'out-of-time' place through the wormhole, and he experienced it as if there was time.

Comment: That's a good point, I wasn't sure how to phrase it.  I updated my answer, on a side note they seemed to exist dually outside and inside of time, at least when outside the wormhole.

Comment: If being locked at home 99.99% of the time and have nearly no influence outside of it means "near god level race", then our prisons are full of near god level races. The Prophets were just a run of the mill aliens living inside a wormhole.

Comment: the fact that these beings exist outside of spacetime would seem to be discordant with notion that they live "inside the wormhole"; a fixed point in spacetime... more or less. Certainly the gates of the celestial temple are fixed. Perhaps this is the only way their multi-dimensional realm can interact with ours.

Answer (score 5):

The [Star Trek Encyclopedia](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) (considered a fully canonical guide to the Star Trek universe) explicitly refers to the entities living within the wormhole as **alien beings**. It does note, however that the Bajorans view them as spiritual beings rather than mere aliens, a major plot point in [DS9 : In the Hands of the Prophets](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_the_Hands_of_the_Prophets_(episode)) :

> **Prophets** : *In the Bajoran religion, the Prophets are spiritual entities who provide wisdom and guidance to the Bajoran people.
>   Bajoran tradition holds that the Prophets were responsible for the
>   nine Orbs that served as sources of wisdom for the people of Bajor.
>   **Many Bajorans believe that the alien beings first encountered in the Bajoran wormhole by Commands Benjamin Sisko in 2369 were in fact the
>   Prophets** These life-forms found the concept of linear time to be
>   totally alien, and Sisko attempted to help them understand the
>   importance of linear existence to Bajorans and humans. Ironically,
>   although Sisko did not believe in the Bajoran religion...*

As to their technology, it's not clear that their powers have any technological basis. Like the Q, Nagilum and various other energy beings, their abilities seem to be biological rather than technological. We can actually see this process occurring in [TNG : Transfigurations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfigurations) where a physical being attains an energy state.

Answer (score 1):

This is absolute speculation on my part but I believe the Prophets were once corporeal and may have evolved on Bajor. They say, many times throughout the series that they are "of Bajor" and have gone to great lengths to contact with the Bajorans and even protect them from an invading Dominion fleet at one point.

Comment: Note that they totally ignored the Cardassian invasion/occupation and were content to allow the Dominion fleet through the wormhole until Sisko told them he was willing to commit suicide to prevent it.

Comment: The occupation occurred outside the wormhole. Other than contacting Bajor and occasionally possessing people it's a bit unclear what, if any, power they have outside the wormhole. Regarding Sisko, they could stop him from going back to the Defiant and attacking the Dominion fleet so the suicide threat wasn't terribly credible.

Comment: “They say, many times throughout the series that they are "of Bajor"” — that’s true, and (spoilers) some Pah-Wraiths end up imprisoned on Bajor for some reason.